# How to properly open MidiDevice and send MidiMessage in Android?

Tags: java, android, midi

I'm working on an app sending Midi messages from an Android smartphone to USB2.0-MIDI cable interface, which is connected with the phone via OTG cable. I'm still stuck on opening the MidiInput/Output Ports, without which I cannot move any further. 
I've already tried everything that came to my mind. MIDI library isn't well covered, I did a huge research, read few Android Midi examples, but at the end here I am asking for help. My implementation seems to be correct, quite similar to what Android presents in the original MidiScope and MidiSynth samples.

At the moment every step of the process is logged. I found out that until the method device.openInputPort(port nr) is called, everything works right. After that nothing more happens. helperIN remains with **null assigned**, event though **mOpenDevice is correctly opened** with all the properties;

```
mManager.openDevice(midiDeviceInfo,
new MidiManager.OnDeviceOpenedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDeviceOpened(MidiDevice device) {
        Log.i("OnDeviceOpened", "before if");
        if (device == null) {
            Log.e("OnDeviceOpened", "cound not open" + midiDeviceInfo);
        } else {
            mOpenDevice = device;
            Log.i("OnDeviceOpened", "opened: " + mOpenDevice.getInfo().getProperties().getString(MidiDeviceInfo.PROPERTY_NAME));

            mListInput = new LinkedList<>();
            MidiInputPort helperIN = null;
            Log.i("OpenInputPort", "inPort Count: " + mOpenDevice.getInfo().getInputPortCount());

            for (int i = 0; i < mOpenDevice.getInfo().getInputPortCount(); i++) {
                Log.i("OpenInputPort", "Trying to open inPort nr: " + i); //last log seen
                helperIN = device.openInputPort(i); //stuck right here!
                Log.i("OpenInputPort", "Opened inPort nr: " + i); //this not seen
                mListInput.add(helperIN);
                if (helperIN == null) {
                    Log.e("openInputPort", "cound not open input port nr: " + i + " " + midiDeviceInfo.getPorts());
                    return;
                }else
                    Log.i("openInputPort", "Port nr: " + i + "connected");
                helperIN = null;
            }
        }
    }
}, null);
```

Edit 1:
Logs:

after few hours, when in plugged the phone in to Android, to once again run the app and get the logs, firts thing I noticed was this. This is quite strange, seems like it took it lots of time to finally decide not to open the port.

```
 04-01 09:13:43.733 7627-7639/com.example.anthonylp.midiandoridtest I/OpenInputPort: Opened inPort nr: 0
 04-01 09:13:43.733 7627-7639/com.example.anthonylp.midiandoridtest E/openInputPort: cound not open input port nr: 0 
 [Landroid.media.midi.MidiDeviceInfo$PortInfo;@e7303d4
```

The actual logs are here:

```
04-01 09:42:11.704 3712-3712/com.example.anthonylp.midiandoridtest I/MidiWhenAdded: Class created
04-01 09:42:52.788 3712-3712/com.example.anthonylp.midiandoridtest I/Midi Info: Name: null
Name: USB2.0-MIDI
04-01 09:42:52.788 3712-3712/com.example.anthonylp.midiandoridtest I/openMidiDevice: midiDeviceInfo not null
04-01 09:42:52.789 3712-3741/com.example.anthonylp.midiandoridtest I/OnDeviceOpened: before if
opened: USB2.0-MIDI
04-01 09:42:52.789 3712-3741/com.example.anthonylp.midiandoridtest I/OpenInputPort: inPort Count: 2
Trying to open inPort nr: 0
```

Nothing more seems to come out of it. 
I expect the code to open the device MidiInputPort and assign it to helperIN, after that add it to mListInput.
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: What is the log output?

Comment: Edit: Logs added.

Comment: That USB interface should have only one port (in each direction). Please show everything reported in the `MidiDeviceInfo`. (And why is there another device without a name?)

Comment: I have no access to the phone and midi interface right now. Those two devices, and two ports in each direction, can this be the property of a low budget Chinese USB2.0-MIDI cable?

Comment: Oops, that cable actually [reports two ports](https://git.kernel.org/linus/1ca8b201309d8426), so this is probably not related with your problem.

Comment: Will the MidiDeviceinfo help, or shall I look for other solution? Is there any other way of implementing midi in android? I already have some experience with Java.midi library, If I could use this one on Android, I think the problems would be omitted.

Comment: I see no obvious problem in your code, and I have no clue if the problem is your code, your hardware, or a bug in Android. Do examples like [MidiKeyboard](https://github.com/philburk/android-midisuite) work for you?